# I delete database on heroku but also this error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table thesis_have_keywords already exists

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm deployed this code on heroku, i'm using CI/CD with travis and heroku. For development reason I'm using SQLite database. I want every time i deploy a repo on heroku, database will be deleted and create again with a file data. I done this but heroku give me the title error.

This my code:

**init**.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin
import os

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(conf_test=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    print("instance path --- " + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'database.db'))
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ''.join(['sqlite:////', os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'database.db')]),
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'],
        JWT_KEY = os.environ['JWT_KEY'],
        SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
    )

    if conf_test is not None:
        app.config.update(conf_test)

    from .model import init_db
    with app.app_context(): init_db()

    from .views import init_views
    with app.app_context(): init_views()

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "it's working..." 

    return app
```

model.py

```
class CurrentState(enum.Enum):
    available = 'AVAILABLE'
    in_progress = 'IN PROGRESS'
    finished = 'FINISHED'

thesis_have_keywords = db.Table('thesis_have_keywords', 
    db.Column('thesis_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("thesis.id")),
    db.Column('keyword_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("keyword.id"))
)

thesis_have_teaching = db.Table('thesis_have_teaching', 
    db.Column('thesis_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("thesis.id")),
    db.Column('teaching_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("teaching.id"))
)

thesis_have_courses = db.Table('thesis_have_courses', 
    db.Column('thesis_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("thesis.id")),
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("degree_courses.id"))
)

class Teacher(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    mail = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    thesis = db.relationship("Thesis", back_populates="teacher")


class Thesis(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False, nullable=False)
    last_modify = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), unique=False, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True)
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), unique=False, nullable=True)
    end_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), unique=False, nullable=True)
    current_state = db.Column(db.Enum(CurrentState), unique=False, nullable=False, default=CurrentState('AVAILABLE'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

    teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("teacher.id"))
    teacher = db.relationship("Teacher", back_populates="thesis")

    keywords = db.relationship("Keyword", back_populates="thesis", secondary=thesis_have_keywords)

    teaching = db.relationship("Teaching", back_populates="thesis", secondary=thesis_have_teaching)

    courses = db.relationship("DegreeCourses", back_populates="thesis", secondary=thesis_have_courses)

class Keyword(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

    thesis = db.relationship("Thesis", back_populates="keywords", secondary=thesis_have_keywords)

class Teaching(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True) 

    thesis = db.relationship("Thesis", back_populates="teaching", secondary=thesis_have_teaching)

class DegreeCourses(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    _type = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

    thesis = db.relationship("Thesis", back_populates="courses", secondary=thesis_have_courses)

def init_db():
    with current_app.app_context():
        if os.path.exists(current_app.instance_path):
            shutil.rmtree(current_app.instance_path)

        try:
            os.makedirs(current_app.instance_path)
        except OSError:
            pass

        db.init_app(current_app)
        db.drop_all()
        db.session.commit()        
        db.create_all()

        with open("server/teachers.json") as teach_file:
            data = json.load(teach_file)

        teacher_entries=[]
        for teacher in data['teachers']:
            teach = Teacher(name=teacher['name'], surname=teacher['surname'], mail=teacher['mail'], id=teacher['id'])
            teacher_entries.append(teach)

        db.session.add_all(teacher_entries)
        db.session.commit()
```

Here every time I delete instance folder and recreate that. I also tried to delete only database file but same error appears.

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table thesis_have_keywords already exists

Comment: What does "every time I delete instance folder" mean? SQLite and Heroku don't play nicely together, but there may be other issues too.

Comment: sorry for my english, i mean that every time i deploy a repository, i delete all instance repository and then i recreate that. I know sqlite is not best option, but for external reason i have to use it. Is only for development reason. But every time on deployment, heroku give me that error.

Comment: There are good reasons not to use SQLite on Heroku. Your data will frequently be lost (not just when you deploy). But I'm still not sure what you mean by "i delete all instance repository and then i recreate that". What command are you running? And where?

Comment: I guess with this code. ```if os.path.exists(current_app.instance_path):
            shutil.rmtree(current_app.instance_path)```. Sorry, I mean that I delete instance folder every time I deploy my code. I tried also to remove only database.db file but also I have same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting _anything_ manually, and you _especially_ shouldn't be doing it in application code like that. When you deploy to Heroku you get a brand new environment each time (though with some buildpacks you may be able to cache libraries).

Comment: You also probably shouldn't be _creating directories_ in code (just like you shouldn't be using SQLite in the first place). I'd like to understand more about your "external reason" for having to use SQLite.

Comment: I create directory like flask tutorial explain to do here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory
The reason for use SQLite with heroku is from my teacher, that said me to use it and not lose time to set up postgresql. Heroku is only temporary server only just for development. But I'm losing so much time trying to resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry but nothing of this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to have other issues in the future (there are very good reasons not to use SQLite on Heroku), but if your `database.db` isn't tracked you shouldn't get that particular error.

Try this:

```
git rm --cached database.db
git commit -m 'Untrack database'
git push heroku master
```

Note that your database will be lost whenever your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day, plus whenever you deploy or change environment variables or add-ons).